# Updating MYSQL table row column sum by appending

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to update a column row inside MYSQL by adding `50` to the last current number.Means column named `sum` was `200` and after query, it will update to `250`.
I can do this by using two query as follow:

```
$add1 = 50;
$sql = "SELECT sum FROM table_name WHERE id = '$id' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$add2 = $row['sum'] + $add1 ;
}
  $sql1 = "UPDATE tabel_name SET sum = '$add2' WHERE id = '$id' "; 
  $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
```

However, is there a better way to do this with less code or by one go?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate values directly in `UPDATE` queries.

```
$add1 = 50;
$sql1 = "UPDATE tabel_name SET sum = sum + $add1 WHERE id = '$id';";
```

In case the type of your column `sum` is not numeric, but contians a string of the given number, you can use the MySQL [`CAST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) function to cast it to a number, calculate it and cast it back to a string again:

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE tabel_name SET sum = CAST((CAST(sum as INT(11)) + $add1) as VARCHAR(11)) WHERE id = '$id';";
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try By

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE tabel_name SET sum = sum + 'YOUR VALUE' WHERE id = '$id'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this sql query:

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE tabel_name SET sum = sum + 50 WHERE id = '$id' ";
```

Comment: Thanks mate I just took the authors sql and changed it in notepad and then copied the same authors sql and pasted it here. Sorry for that.. Have updated the sql now..

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `UPDATE` for this, just change your query like:

`$sql = "UPDATE table_name SET sum=sum+value_you_want  WHERE id = '$id' ";`